# I save json data to json file but then I can not load it -- Error: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

This is a toy example where I save data in json format to a json file but then I can not load it.

```
import json  

# python objects can store in json format  
value = [
    
    ['sentence one' , {'entities' : []}],
    
    ['sentence two' , {'entities' : ['TITLE']}],
    
    ['sentence three' , {'entities' : []}],
        
        ] 

# the json file to save the output data   
save_file = open("savedata.json", "w")  

json.dump(value, save_file, indent = 6)  

save_file.close()
```

I open the 'savedata.json' file with a text editor and this is the content:

[the content of the savedata.json file when opened with a text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qafzG.png)

When I try to load the json file I get an error:

```
json.loads("savedata.json")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 1
----> 1 json.loads("savedata.json")

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\json\__init__.py:346, in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    341     s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')
    343 if (cls is None and object_hook is None and
    344         parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    345         parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 346     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    347 if cls is None:
    348     cls = JSONDecoder

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\json\decoder.py:337, in JSONDecoder.decode(self, s, _w)
    332 def decode(self, s, _w=WHITESPACE.match):
    333     """Return the Python representation of ``s`` (a ``str`` instance
    334     containing a JSON document).
    335 
    336     """
--> 337     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338     end = _w(s, end).end()
    339     if end != len(s):

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\json\decoder.py:355, in JSONDecoder.raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353     obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354 except StopIteration as err:
--> 355     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356 return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `json.loads` is for loading a string containing json data. To load file containing json, use `json.load`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `json.load` instead of `json.loads`.

In order to serialize data to JSON strings, and convert JSON strings back into Python data, you use the `json.dumps()` and `json.loads()` functions respectively, with an "s" at the end.

In order to write data as JSON *files*, and to read data in from JSON files, you use the `json.dump()` and `json.load()` functions respectively, *without* an "s" at the end.

Refer to the [Source Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) for more details as to the difference between the two methods, as you might need to use one over the other.

Comment: Don't say "there is a different", [explain that difference in your post](/help/how-to-answer). Even if you link out to the documentation. Much like questions, answers should have all the details even if they link out to more detailed information.

Comment: You're right. Thank you for reminding me. I updated with more details.